# Updating eclipse 3.1.2 for JbossIDE 1.6.0-GA

Tags: eclipse, jboss

how can i update the eclipse bundled with my jbossIDE? Which eclipse do I need to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JBossIDE (now known as [JBossTools](http://www.jboss.org/tools), a collection of tools/projects including [JBoss server](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/as/html/index.html)) is best "updated" as a new, separate installation from the one you already have.

I would also recommend referencing a new workspace, in order to not change/corrupt your existing workspace.

In other words, don't touch a working installation, make a new one.

Following the [installation guide](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_2), you will need at least an [Eclipse3.6.1 Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1).

The you can use their [update site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/) in order to add what you need:

[image: JBoss Tools update site]